# UICollectionView won't reloadData() after UIImagePickerController dismisses

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I have a small issue in that after selecting an image from UIImagePickerController (and saving to Parse because my UICollectionView populates from my images on Parse), my UICollectionView will not load the newly saved image until I leave that viewController and go back to it. I've tried just about every work around that I can think of. Where should I be putting my code to save and dismiss controller?

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    let imagePicture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name: "imageFile.jpg", data: image)

    let saveImage = PFObject(className: "Gallery")
    saveImage["imageFile"] = imageFile
    saveImage["dogName"] = self.dogSelectedName
    saveImage["userID"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
    saveImage["dogID"] = self.dogObjectID
    saveImage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (Bool, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("There was an error")
        } else {
            print("New Gallery object saved: \(saveImage)")
        }
    }

    self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems())
    self.collectionView.reloadData()

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in}
}
```

After debugging, I notice a lot of the time it saves my object after the view appears (or depending where I write the code, before the view appears) and still will not reload the collection view until I leave and come back. I've put:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

In multiple places in my code but still same result.. How else can/should I be setting this up? Any help is lots of help!! Thanks.

Comment: What function are you using to populate your `UICollectionView`?

Comment: let findPhotos = PFQuery(className: "Gallery")
        findPhotos.whereKey("dogID", equalTo: self.dogObjectID)
        findPhotos.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        findPhotos.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if let users = objects {
                for object in users {
                    self.photoData.addObject(object)
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    print("Fetched \(self.dogSelectedName)'s \(self.photoData.count) Images")
                }
            }
        }

Comment: This is all in a function called lookUpForPhotos() which is called on viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lookUpPhotos` function is fine, but you can update the `collectionView` at the end of your query.

```
func lookUpPhotos() {

    let findPhotos = PFQuery(className: "Gallery")
    findPhotos.whereKey("dogID", equalTo: self.dogObjectID)
    findPhotos.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    findPhotos.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { 
        (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let users = objects {
            for object in users { 
                self.photoData.addObject(object)
                print("Fetched \(self.dogSelectedName)'s \(self.photoData.count) Images") 
            } 
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call the `lookUpPhotos` function again once you send the data.

```
saveImage.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (Bool, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print("There was an error")
    } else {
        print("New Gallery object saved: \(saveImage)")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in
                self.lookUpPhotos()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: since we're on the subject I'm having the same problem on my other viewController that shows the image full screen once chosen from the previous view. Instead, when I delete the photo and object, I presentViewController(galleryVC, animated: true, completion: nil) and it doesn't update the lookUpPhotos() method in time so that image i just deleted is still there. But when I leave and come back its gone. I can't pull my lookUpPhotos() method from the previous viewController bc I'm on a new one.. Any suggestions? Put some more code in the deleteInBackgroundWithBlock block?

Answer (score 0):

You saved it in Parse, but it doesn't seem like you're adding it to your dataSource.

So if your `UICollectionView`'s data source of `Dog`s or `DogImage`s is an array called

`var dogArray = []`

You need to add your dog to that array in `didFinishPickingImage`

`dogArray.append(imagePicture)`

Hope it helps

Comment: He said that his `UICollectionView` is populated from Parse so he should actually be calling the function that is called initially to load the images after he sends the image to Parse.

Comment: `UICollectionView`s work with data sources. You can't just 'populate from Parse'

Comment: Obviously. He is putting the data from Parse into a data source. When working with data from a server, it is best to not get them out of sync. Even though he sends the data to Parse, he should still reload the data back into the data source to be sure that the data was stored correctly. Else, he is just blindly updating locally.

Comment: No, you're adding an extra API request for nothing. `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` responds with a boolean value that tells you whether the save succeeded. If it was successful, add it to your dataSource@Caleb

Comment: Furthermore, it is a fairly common UX tactic to add data before it is saved, in order to make the app feel faster than it really is.

Comment: Adding data before it is saved seems like an unsafe idea. I think that the application should be honest with users and show the real data. Different practices I guess.

Comment: Guys, thank you so much for both your inputs. @ray my datasource is an array, but its an array of pfObjects.. Do you think I should change it up so that its an array of images? Then I can just go photoData.addObject(image).. I can't think of another way to add the object that I just saved right to the array.

Comment: @bme003 if images is all your datasource provides then yes. If not, then no. And by the way, for Caleb's answer above, you should remove all of the `dispatch_async` wrappers as they are useless and complicate your code for nothing.

Comment: Ok @ray thanks a lot! I think simplifying my code and re-structuring it will be worth it in the end.