# Add data and reload CollectionView after dismiss ImagePicker - Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, reloaddata

In my app, user can pick an image with imagepicker. After he chose, I want to update my collectionview (or tableview) with the new image.
But even if the reload funcs are called and the new item is in my list, the UI is not refreshed.

EDIT TO HIGHLIGHT THIS : I simplify code with cancel dismiss instead because the behavior is the same. 
I know I have to call didFinishWith... but I want to highlight the behavior causing by the dismiss.

```
var files = [File]() // populate my collectionview or tableview

// ... code
// ... more code 

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true) {

        let newFile = File(name: "test")
        self.files.append(newFile)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            // self.tableView?.reloadData() has the same behavior 
        }
    }
}
```

If I print in collectionView-CellForItemAt ... I see that I have my new element in the list, but it's not show on the screen.

I try differents things, but nothing works or seems very dirty to me. Any idea to perform this properly ?

(I already see this topic : [UICollectionView won't reloadData() after UIImagePickerController dismisses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366830/uicollectionview-wont-reloaddata-after-uiimagepickercontroller-dismisses) )

EDIT FOR MORE INFO :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.files.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.file = self.files[indexPath.row]
        cell.filenameLabel.text = self.files[indexPath.row].name
        // other customization of cell
        print(cell.file.name)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You should use this method : `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` and show your code of `CellForItemAt `

Comment: @Lyume I think for this type of requirement you should go with PHASSET

Comment: As I said, I just show you the example with cancel to simplify the understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing imagePickerControllerDidCancel.  If the user picks an image the picker doesn't call the delegate with imagePickerControllerDidCancel, it calls [didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller)

Comment: I know, I just simplify the code, because the behavior is the same.

Comment: instead of .reloadData() call collectionView.insertItems(at:) This method asserts if your model doesn't match the collectionView, which is likely the case.  The assertion should tell you if you are short on cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try my objective c code :

```
[objCollectionView reloadData];

[objCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];

 [objCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                }];
```

Comment: Thanks, but nothing changes. I still have my object in console but not in UI.

Comment: self.files.append(newFile) what is use of this ? and what is type of self.files ?

Comment: self.files populates my collectionView and is type of [File]. File is a simple object with a name, an image, etc.

I edit my post so you can see where I use self.files